# Why does uniq utility give me unexpected results?

Tags: sort, uniq

I'm creating a shellscript that will print out various filetypes we have in our directory. It pretty much works, however, for some odd reason when I try to use uniq on my output, it doesn't work. This is my input (and value of `$FILE_TYPE`)

```
POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
ASCII text
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

However when I use

```
FILE_TYPE_COUNT=`echo "$FILE_TYPE" | sort | uniq -c`
```

this is the result it prints

```
  1 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 ASCII text
  1 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
  1 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Obviously it should be

```
  1 POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 ASCII text
  2 Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
  1 UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note shell variables by convention are lowercase.

Comment: There is missing code. How can we help, if you don't show a minimum, but sufficient code, to show the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not sorting the file before filtering it. From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html):

> Note: `uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u` without `uniq`. Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by `LC_COLLATE`.

You also need to process *all* the lines you want to count in one go. Currently, you're processing file types one at a time, so `uniq -c` correctly tells you you have one of each — it only ever sees one file type at a time.

```
file * | sort | uniq -c
```

would be more appropriate (presumably with a more specific glob, or even a list of files to process).

Comment: Thanks somehow I overlooked it, however since that is STDOUT of a certain echo, sort -u doesnt work on it. Any idea how could I sort it out? basically it's FILE_TYPE=`file -b "$MY_FILE"` in a for loop echo'd out, so FILE_TYPE_COUNT=`echo "$FILE_TYPE" | sort -u` sadly doesnt work on it

Comment: @Rawrplus You need to pass the whole output to a call to `sort`, rather than pass each line individually to a separate.call to `sort`. If you don't understand how to do that, ask a new question with your actual code (the full script, not just one line).